# Unity not switching scenes and there is no error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Unity Version 2020.3.25f1. External Libraries: FMOD engine, and websocketsharp. In the websocketsharp callback "OnOpen", this is the code:

```
Debug.Log("Connected."); 
conn.Send("Sucessfully connected!"); 
Debug.Log("Switching to 'Lobby' scene."); 
SceneManager.LoadScene("Lobby", LoadSceneMode.Single);
Debug.Log("I should be on the 'Lobby' scene now.");
```

The problem is it executes line #3, but then line #4 does not execute, and it does not do the final "Debug.Log". It seems to get stuck trying to load the scene, but It has already switched from the MainMenu scene to the loading scene so it should be working. I have searched for hours to find anyone with the same problem. It is also still running the Update() function so it is not that the whole program is freezing.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should call it in `Awake()` or `LateUpdate()` or for the scene maybe you should use `SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync()` hopefully this [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync.html) may help you.